# Better way to break out a date?

Tags: python, pandas

This piece of code should be self-explanatory and it's also a choke-point in my process. Any way to do this better?

```
geoset['MonthInt'] = pd.to_datetime(geoset['Date received']).dt.month # Add a month
geoset['YearInt'] = pd.to_datetime(geoset['Date received']).dt.year # Add a year
geoset['DayInt'] = pd.to_datetime(geoset['Date received']).dt.day # Add a day of month
geoset['DayOfWeekInt'] = pd.to_datetime(geoset['Date received']).dt.dayofweek # Add a day of week
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious optimisation would be converting 'Date received' to pandas datetime once, for example (if you need to retain original column):

```
geoset['pddate_received'] = pd.to_datetime(geoset['Date received'])
geoset['MonthInt'] = geoset['pddate_received'].dt.month # Add a month
geoset['YearInt'] = geoset['pddate_received'].dt.year # Add a year
geoset['DayInt'] = geoset['pddate_received'].dt.day # Add a day of month
geoset['DayOfWeekInt'] = geoset['pddate_received'].dt.dayofweek # Add a day of week
```